# PHPExcel and Text Wrapping

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpexcel

I know that this line of code will make the cell text-wrap:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

'D1' being the chosen cell.

Instead of using this code for every cell I need wrapped, is there a way to make the entire Excel Worksheet automatically wrap everything?

Or is there a better practice technique to use for specified columns?

Comment: did you think about looping to every cell and apply the wrapper ?

Comment: Looping is highly inefficient, so I wouldn't recommend it, but setting style for a range of cells is a simple call

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Apply to a range:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1:E999')
    ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Apply to a column

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1:D'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow())
    ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem. It works perfect but it shows last word of the string? I want to show first few characters which can fit into the cell?

Comment: @virus - then perhaps you need to set vertical alignment as well

Comment: Just a heads up that setting the range to 999 will increase file size.

Comment: It'll only increase file size if you have fewer than 999 rows, adjust that value to suit the size of your spreadsheet

Answer (score 34):

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: Probably the best answer here. I don't know if this method was around when the question was posted, but it's definitely a nifty way to wrap text in all cells of the document.

Comment: yes, best answer to make automatically text-wrap all cell in doc regardless of any sheet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply to column

```
$highestRow = $$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
    $sheet->getStyle("D$row")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
}
```

Comment: No need to wrap when you can use a range. getStyle('A1:AI100')

Comment: @MH how do I wrap  multiple columns, not range